# Understanding constraints in use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I've just read a book about UML and an currently trying to create a use case diagram of one simple domain.

The domain states:

- There are two kinds of users: default and vip.
- Default user can create no more than 10 posts.
- Vip user has no restrictions.

What is the right way to bring this restriction into use case diagram?
Is my diagram correct?

[image]

If it's correct, can I model the same way the next statement?

*User can give only one star to post*

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost correct. You should write the text in curly brackets. That will identify it to be a constraint. Further you should use the correct case for `Default User`. Eventually you can link the constraint to the actor as well. And yes, you can go on like that. Maybe, `Rate Post` is another use case. Think about that.

Comment: thank you! Sorry for bothering you but could you please give me one more advice? If my diagram is large (about 25 use cases), can I split it into several use case diagrams ?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can create a diagram per UC if you want to show details per UC or you can group them logically (to what ever makes sense). Also you can create one overview diagram showing the plain UCs without the constraints.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: I'd also encourage you to look for a UML tool. Personally I'm using Enterprise Architect because of it's price performance ratio. Definitely because of its crude GUI.

Comment: I see, but I'm currently just a poor student who works as a trainee in one company. I use UML Designer. But thank you I will check it out tomorrow

Comment: Ah, I see. I've been in that situation once. Try convincing your boss to buy something he can use to reduce his tax payments ;-)